# Long table inside the long table

Tags: tables, longtable

Is there any possibility to fix the longtable inside the longtable, as per client requirement. Please suggest how to fix this.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{llllllllll}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \begin{longtable}{llll}
                                        1&2&3&1&1\\
                                        1&5&4&9&7\\
                                        1&2&3&1&1\\
                                        1&5&4&9&7\\
                                        1&2&3&1&1\\
                                        1&5&4&9&7\\
                                        1&2&3&1&1\\
                                        1&5&4&9&7\\
                                        \end{longtable} \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you should nest a long table? it shouldn't be braked over page since it is one cell (row) of mine table. a `tabular should do your job:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{*{10}l}
1  & 1  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1  & 1  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1  & 1  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1  & 1  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1  & 1  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \begin{tabular}{@{} *{5}{l}}
                                        1 & 5 & 4 & 9 & 7\\
                                        1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 1\\
                                        1 & 5 & 4 & 9 & 7\\
                                        1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 1\\
                                        1 & 5 & 4 & 9 & 7\\
                                        1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 1\\
                                      \end{tabular}\\
1  & 1  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1  & 1  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1  & 1  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1  & 1  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1  & 1  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just use a 14 column longtable from the start.  This will allow you to pagebreak anywhere.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\skipnine}{&&&&&&&&&}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{llllllllllllll}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1&2&3&1&1\\
\skipnine 1&5&4&9&7\\
\skipnine 1&2&3&1&1\\
\skipnine 1&5&4&9&7\\
\skipnine 1&2&3&1&1\\
\skipnine 1&5&4&9&7\\
\skipnine 1&2&3&1&1\\
\skipnine 1&5&4&9&7\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 10 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```